# Can not find _app.js in nextJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, next.js, frontend

I am using `npx create-next-app` to create my NextJs project and now I want to add global style for it by `bootstrap`

After downloading `bootstrap`, it suggested me adding global style in `pages/_app.js` but I found no file like it. Thanks for helping me

[image]

Comment: is your project working without _app.js ?

Comment: @BilalMohammad yeah, it worked perfectly but I still need add global style =(

Comment: You should have _app.js in the pages folder. Try running `npx create-next-app` again?

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya I did but It is not there

Comment: @TâmĐỗ What's inside of your pages/index.js? Can you show that please?

Comment: share the content of index.js file

Comment: @TâmĐỗ If `pages/_app.js` file doesn't exist then simply add it yourself. I'd recommend a read through [Next.js Custom `App`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app). You can also have a look at https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-react-bootstrap for an example on how to integrate `react-bootstrap` in Next.js.

Answer (score 2):

You create your `pages/_app.js`, you place code below

```
import React from 'react';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
      return (
            <Component {...pageProps} />
      );
    }
```

To add bootstrap, you create styles folder in `/public`, you add your .css file of bootstrap (imagine it's `bootstrap.css`). After, you add import to your `app.js` file, and the example below:

```
import React from 'react';
import "../styles/bootstrap.css";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
      return (
            <Component {...pageProps} />
      );
    }
```

The possible reason you don't have `app.js` is because you didn't build your project yet

Answer (score 0):

when you make a new Nextjs project you don't have this file

you should create this file in root pages

_app.js  or _app.tsx (if you use typescript)

```
const MyApp=()=>{
    return(
       enter code here
    )
  }
export default MyApp
```

Comment: then where I import _app.js, just create and export for nothing? Thanks

Comment: it was import automatic in all of page

Answer (score 0):

Add _document.js file in pages/_document.js, you can add your global style in this file [index.jsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiydp.png) see documentation:
[Custom Document Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document)

Comment: No. Global style can be stay inside [_app.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app) file.